# Why isn't this function modifying the final output?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm doing something simple: read a file, replace a character, and output the modified content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs')
  , filename = process.argv[2]

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.log('Usage: node ' + process.argv[1] + ' FILENAME')
  process.exit(1)
}

function replaceCharacters(data) {
  data = data
    .replace(/"(?=\b|\*|')/g, '“')

  console.log(data)
}

function saveHtml(data) {
  fs.writeFile("untitled.html", data, function(err) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log(data)
  })
}

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err

  replaceCharacters(data)

  saveHtml(data)
})
```

The problem is, `replaceCharacters` is not affecting the final output. Instead of curly opening quotes, I'm still getting the straight ones.

What am I doing wrong?

(The quotes do replace if a move the content from `replaceCharacters` into `fs.readFile`).

**EDIT:**

The value does change inside the function `console.log(data)` outputs the data with curly quotes.

Comment: Does the value change while still inside the function? Or does it never chance?

Comment: @Jordumus Yes, the value does change inside the function.

Comment: T.J. Crowder below has the right solution for you then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's replacing them, but never *returning* what it replaces:

```
function replaceCharacters(data) {
  data = data
    .replace(/"(?=\b|\*|')/g, '“')

  console.log(data)

  return data; // <====
}
```

Then when you use it:

```
    data = replaceCharacters(data)
//  ^^^^^^^
```

As you seem to know, `replace` creates a **new** string with the replacement, it doesn't update the string in place. (It can't, strings in JavaScript are immutable.) In your `replaceCharacters` function, you're updating the `data` argument with the result, but that doesn't change the variable that `replaceCharacters` was called with, just the argument within the function call. So just as you have to write `data = data.replace(...)` *within* your `replaceCharacters` function, you have to return the result *from* your `replaceCharacters` function and use that return value.

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking as well. That's why I asked if it was changing inside the function.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks. So `functions` generally always need a return? In not, in which cases they don't need them?

Comment: @alexchenco: Functions only need a `return` if they need to return something (he said, aware of the circular language :-) ). Your function does because it has no way to reach out and change the variable that was passed into it; it can only change its argument, which is a purely local change and has no effect on the variable passed into it. So to feed back its results, it has to return them.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for the explanation! Sorry, I'm an art major, so this kind of stuff is difficult to me.